# Insert method for BST

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

I was able to implement a Boolean insert method for a binary search tree. It takes a generic data and inserts a key into the BST. My code does not allow duplicates, and returns false if a key is already presented in the BST. It returns true if the insertion is successful.

The problem is that, I think its not increment the number of elements present in the BST and is only able to reach 2 elements.

I have tried to debug it and see why my output and expected is off by one.

Here is my constructors and methods

```
public class BSTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Iterable {

    private int nelems;
    private BSTNode root;
    private BSTNode curr;
    private BSTNode keyHere;

    protected class BSTNode {

        T key;
        LinkedList<T> dataList;
        BSTNode left;
        BSTNode right;


        public BSTNode(BSTNode left, BSTNode right, LinkedList<T> dataList, T key) {
            //TODO
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.key = key;
            setDataList(dataList);
        }

        public BSTNode(BSTNode left, BSTNode right, T key) {
            //TODO
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.key = key;
            this.dataList = new LinkedList<T>();

        }

        public T getKey() {
            //TODO
            return this.key;
        }

        public BSTNode getLeft() {
            //TODO
            return this.left;
        }

        public BSTNode getRight() {
            //TODO
            return this.right;
        }

        public LinkedList<T> getDataList() {
            //TODO
            return this.dataList;
        }

        public void setleft(BSTNode newleft) {
            //TODO
            this.left = newleft;
        }

        public void setright(BSTNode newright) {
            //TODO
            this.right = newright;
        }

        public void setDataList(LinkedList<T> newData) {
            //TODO
            this.dataList = newData;
        }

        public void addNewInfo(T data) {
            //TODO
            if (data != null)
            {
                getDataList().addLast(data);
            }

        }

        public boolean removeInfo(T data) {


            return dataList.remove(data);

        }
    }

    public BSTree() {
        //TODO
        root = null;
        nelems = 0;
        curr = null;
        keyHere = null;

    }
```

Here is my code for insertion

```
public boolean insert(T key) {


        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if (findKey(key)) // this method returns true if key is in BST
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (getSize() == 0)
        {
            LinkedList<T> linked = new LinkedList<T>();
            BSTNode node = new BSTNode(null, null, linked,key);
            root = node;
            curr = root;
            nelems = 1;
        }
        else
         {
            if (curr.getKey().compareTo(key) < 0)
            {
                if(curr.getRight() != null)
                {
                    curr = curr.getRight();
                    insert(key);
                }
                else
                {
                    LinkedList<T> linked = new LinkedList<T>();
                    BSTNode node = new BSTNode(null,null,linked,key);
                    curr.setright(node);
                    nelems += 1 ;
                    curr = root;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (curr.getLeft() != null)
                {
                    curr = curr.getLeft();
                    insert(key);
                }
                else
                {
                    LinkedList<T> linked = new LinkedList<T>();
                    BSTNode node = new BSTNode(null,null,linked,key);
                    curr.setleft(node);
                    curr = root;
                    nelems += 1;
                }

            }
         }

        return true;

    }
public boolean findKey(T key) {

        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if (getSize() == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(curr.getKey().compareTo(key)!= 0)
        {
            if(curr.getKey().compareTo(key) < 0)
            {
                if (curr.getRight() != null)
                {
                    curr = curr.getRight();
                    findKey(key);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.curr = root;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (curr.getLeft() != null)
                {
                    curr = curr.getLeft();
                    findKey(key);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.curr = root;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.keyHere = curr;
            this.curr = root;
            return true;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

When I would insert a value to a tree it keeps track of the first 2 elements but after adding the third one it stops increment element for some reason.
here is my testers

```
public class BSTreeTester{
    BSTree<Integer> tree1;
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        tree1 = new BSTree<Integer>();
    }
    public void testinsert() {
        tree1.insert(new Integer(100));
        assertEquals("The size of the tree should be 1", 1, tree1.getSize());
        assertEquals("The root of the tree should be 100", 100,
                (int)tree1.getRoot().getKey());

        tree1.insert(new Integer(200));
        assertEquals("The size of the tree shoul dbe 2", 2, tree1.getSize());
        assertEquals("The root of the tree should still be 100", 100,
                (int)tree1.getRoot().getKey());
        tree1.insert(new Integer(300));
        assertEquals("The size of the tree should be 3", 3, tree1.getSize());
        assertEquals("The root of the tree should still be 100", 100,
                (int)tree1.getRoot().getKey());

}
```

When inserting the 3rd new integer the expected should be 3, but its giving me 2.

Comment: You don't show the code for `findKey`, which is one way this code may fail to insert something.  Also the code for `getSize` isn't shown (but I assume it just returns `nelems`).  Check that `tree1.insert(new Integer(300))` actually returns `true`, as I suspect it doesn't.  I tested the code (as far as it was posted) and inserted 6 elements, and `nelems` was 6 as expected.

Comment: @john16384 i  updated my code, and yes getsize return nelems. and yes it did returned false on the third insertion.

Comment: @john16384 it was my findkey method which failed my code!